# Jquery ajax get - how to output data based on condition?

Tags: jquery

there, I have a such piece of code:

```
$("#choose").change(function(){
$.get("get_results.php", {name: $("#choose").val()},
                                  function(data){
                                            if(data !== ""){
                                            $("#results").html(data);
                                            }else{
                                            $("#results").html('<strong>Sorry, no records.</strong>'); 
                                            }
                                  });
 });
```

Now the problem is that the first condition ( if(data !== "") ) is always evaluated correctly and executed, but the else clause ('Sorry, no records') never shows up. Can anyone spot the error? Data passed for the else clause is specifically "". Thank You.

P.S. I think I have to clarify my problem - can anyone suggest how 'data' could be evaluated and processed, because 'else' never gets executed whatever 'if' clause I do and whatever data I throw into it.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian and Jamie, I'll give a point for your answers, because its working solutions, but it doesn't solve the problem. Yor solutions give the same result as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys, I found the answer myself - although I echoed out an empty string, additional characters were added to the 'data', so it was never evaluated as an empty string. As an alternative I outputed 'none' for the 'if' clause and checked it trimmed with a Jquery 'trim' function. Here's the code. I hope it will help someone.

```
$("#select").change(function(){
       $.get("get_result.php", {name: $("#select").val()},function(data){
    data = jQuery.trim(data);
       if(data != 'none'){
       $("#result").html(data);
       }else{
       $("#result").html('<strong>Sorry, no records</strong>'); 
       }
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

I think you could also say

```
if(data.length > 0)
{

}
```

plus you have 2 equals symbols in the other example? maybe just try '!='

Comment: No worries at all - If it's giving you the same result, maybe your dataset is never empty?

Comment: Well, its empty string echoed out, thats for sure: (echo '';) from php and firebug doesn't show anything in response in that case.

Answer (score 1):

in your php file try echo ""; instead of echo '';

or return a null value (echo null;)

```
if(data !== null)
{

}
```